# How many golden guns are in the game and what is their purpose?

Tags: max-payne-3

I've played the first three chapters of the game, and until now I've just found one of the golden gun pieces.

How many of these guns are in the game? Do they have any purpose or is it just an "achievement" to collect all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Golden guns do 10% more damage and have increased clip size. I believe all of the guns get a golden version, each accessible in a particular mission.

Here's a [location guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/max-payne-3/Golden_Guns).

Comment: Is it just for the chapter where you find them or you get to keep them for the whole game?

Comment: The whole game.

Comment: Some golden guns, like the golden [Sawed-off Shotgun](http://maxpayne.wikia.com/wiki/Sawed-off_shotgun), is not affected by the increased clip size (its golden version's clip size is still two). What other guns don't have an increased clip size?