# How to equip and use the golden guns?

Tags: max-payne-3

I'm in my first playthrough of Max Payne 3 and I can't figure out how to equip the golden guns, once all the pieces have been found.  Are those available later, in some sort of "new game+" playthrough ?  Or does it have something to do with multiplayer ?
Or it's just some kind of an achievement (but I don't think so, regarding [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/73374/15726)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I remember, once all parts are collected, golden guns will automatically replace their regular versions. Try selecting another chapter to play, if you currently don't have the gun which you collected all gold parts of and you would like to try it.

This seems to be supported by [posts in this thread at xbox360achievements.org](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=370709) and this [one at gamefaqs.com](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/958969-/63126039).

Also, check if Golden Guns are enabled at: Main Menu -> Settings -> Gameplay -> Golden Gun Effects On/Off.

In Multiplayer:

> Go to Arsenal then Loadout. Select any Loadout and select any weapon you wish to use. Once selected [press the button for] "modify". In this modify screen the bottom option is called "tint".

<sup>Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/958970-max-payne-3/answers?qid=322942</sup>

> The gold paint job is at the bottom of the "attachments" menu for each weapon.

<sup>Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/958970-/62871855</sup>
In Multiplayer, the golden guns are just cosmetic customization and provide no bonuses ([unlike the Single Player golden guns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73372/4797)).

Comment: Oooow, ok.  Maybe I'm playing with it from the beginning then, without knowing it (the guns are not always easy to see, as Max is not facing the camera).

Comment: @Anto I had to revise my answer a bit, based on re-reading the thread I linked to and the other thread that I added. This seems to be also closer to what you experienced.